# dplyr: group events in a session together

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame as shown below. I want to group the events of each "unique" session together. For example, in the following case, id number 1 engaged with my system twice, and had two sessions. I want to "spread" (tidyr) the data, but per each session. Not per id. How can I use dplyr and tidyr to do it?

```
> df
  id event                time
1  1 start 2015-05-16 22:46:53
2  1 valid 2015-05-16 22:46:56
3  1   end 2015-05-16 22:46:59
4  2 start 2015-05-16 22:46:53
5  2   bad 2015-05-16 22:47:00
6  1 start 2015-05-16 22:49:05
7  1   bad 2015-05-16 22:49:09
>
```

Desired output is something like the following:

```
> df1
  nid           starttime           validtime             badtime             endtime
1   1 2015-05-16 22:46:53 2015-05-16 22:46:56                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:46:59
2   2 2015-05-16 22:46:53                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:47:00                <NA>
3   1 2015-05-16 22:49:05                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:49:09                <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. I am not sure if you have time as a date object or a character object. Here, I created `time` as a date object in `mydf`. When I reshaped the data, I realised that `spread()` converted the time object to numeric. I, therefore, decided to convert `time` to character first. Then, I created a new variable called `group` which helps reshaping the data with `spread()`. In order to keep the order you wanted, I used `arrange()`. I changed the column names with `select()`. Finally, I converted `time` to a date object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1),
                   event = c("start", "valid", "end", "start", "bad", "start", "bad"),
                   time = as.POSIXct(c("2015-05-16 22:46:53", "2015-05-16 22:46:56", "2015-05-16 22:46:59",
                                       "2015-05-16 22:46:53", "2015-05-16 22:47:00", "2015-05-16 22:49:05",
                                       "2015-05-16 22:49:09"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mutate(mydf, time = as.character(time),
             group = cumsum(c(T, diff(id) != 0))) %>%
spread(event, time) %>%
arrange(group) %>%
select(id, starttime = start, validtime = valid, badtime = bad, endtime = end) %>%
mutate_each(funs(as.POSIXct(., format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), starttime:endtime)

#  id           starttime           validtime             badtime             endtime
#1  1 2015-05-16 22:46:53 2015-05-16 22:46:56                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:46:59
#2  2 2015-05-16 22:46:53                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:47:00                <NA>
#3  1 2015-05-16 22:49:05                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:49:09                <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`.  Using `rleid` and `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v1.9.5 (Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)), we can convert the 'long' format to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(df)[, gr:= rleid(id)], id+gr~paste0(event, 'time'), 
             value.var='time')[order(starttime)][, c(1, 5:6, 3:4), with=FALSE]
#   id           starttime           validtime             badtime
#1:  1 2015-05-16 22:46:53 2015-05-16 22:46:56                <NA>
#2:  2 2015-05-16 22:46:53                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:47:00
#3:  1 2015-05-16 22:49:05                <NA> 2015-05-16 22:49:09
#              endtime
#1: 2015-05-16 22:46:59
#2:                <NA>
#3:                <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
 event =   c("start", 
"valid", "end", "start", "bad", "start", "bad"),
 time = structure(c(1431816413, 
 1431816416, 1431816419, 1431816413, 1431816420, 1431816545, 
 1431816549
  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")), 
 .Names = c("id", 
 "event", "time"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
 "7"), class = "data.frame")
```